# Write/Read a kdtree into a file

Tags: c++, kdtree

I am new to C++ and data structure, I have code to approximate the nearest neighbors, and for that I implemented a Kd-tree in C++.

My question how can I write the kd-tree into a file and how to read it from that file?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

See [boost::serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/doc/index.html). You may choose between several output formats - plain text, xml, binary

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to C++, you just have to understand what exactly do you need and implement it in a correct simple way. So no boost dependency is needed.
At first - your kd-tree likely stores pointers to objects and do not own them. Consider dumping\loading via structures that actually own objects (that is responsible for their life time), thus avoiding duplicates and leaks. At second - usually trees are not stored in files, instead they are constructed each time you load some geometry because they require more storage than just an array of objects and they can contain duplicates, that you need to track separately. 
Thereby, if you figured out who owns your objects, your read\write procedures will look like

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::string filename = "geometty_dump.txt"      
  if (argc == 2) {  // filename explicitly provided
    filename = *argv[1];
  }
  ProblemDriver driver; // stores geometry owner\owners
  bool res = driver.GetGeometry(filename);
  if (res) res = driver.SolveProblem();
  if (res) res = driver.DumpGeometry();
  return res;
}
```

In the place where you access geometric data itself (like `double x, y;`) you must include `<iostream>`, try to read something about C++ i\o if your question is about it. Objects that own x, y must have friend correspondent functions

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream out&, const MyPoint& point) {
  out << point.x() << point.y() << '\n';
}
ostream& operator>> (istream in&, MyPoint& point) {
  double x, y;
  in >> x >> y;
  point.set(x, y);
}
```

Meaning you create `ofstream` and `ifstream` repectively in `ProblemDriver` methods (`GetGeometry`, `DumpGeometry`) that invoke these functions.